# Concatenate column of every n-th row while calculating sum of all n rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very specific way I want to transform a pandas dataframe.
It currently looks like this:

```
    CREATED_DATE    COUNT
0   2018-10-01      27
1   2018-10-02      27
2   2018-10-03      34
3   2018-10-04      23
4   2018-10-05      23
        ...
```

What I want is to combine my data in to 7-day-chunks, which means I want to concatenate every first and the seventh's CREATED_DATE value, while summing up all seven COUNT values.
Something like this:

```
        CREATED_DATE                COUNT
    0   2018-10-01 to 2018-10-07    163
    1   2018-10-08 to 2018-10-14    183
    2   2018-10-15 to 2018-10-21    301
    3   2018-10-22 to 2018-10-28    142
    4   2018-10-29 to 2018-11-05    95
                  ...
```

I tried several approaches using transform, but somehow never end up with the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby().agg()`:

```
(df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//7)
   .agg({'CREATED_DATE': lambda x: x.min() + ' to ' + x.max(),
         'COUNT': 'sum'})
)
```

Comment: Might be related to my Python with v3.7, but I get a `SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported`

Comment: @Michael It's rather a Pandas version thingie. Should run fine for Pandas 2.4+

Comment: Version check says `1.0.5`. Problem is, that the environment I'm using does not allow to update the packages easily. I will take a look if I can translate your approach for my pandas version

Comment: @Michael correction Pandas 0.24+. You can try lazy groupby `groups = df.groupby(...); group['CREATED_DATE'].apply(lambda x:...)` to see if it works.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? I'm not completely following on how to achieve it that way

Comment: Nevermind, I used the wrong key. Also had to transform my `x.min` and `x.max` to a string since they were datetime objects. Works perfectly